# Firebase Stripe Webhook API to manage subscribing customers

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

So I have a firebase web app that offers a premium subscription.

Now the logs in Stripe and Google Cloud says most of the webhook is 200 OK, ***most*** of the events. But! I cant get Firebase to store the newly customer data in my Firestore.

I get this:

> {
> "error": "Webhook handler failed. View function logs in Firebase."
> }

And: textPayload:

> ❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for  Stripe event [evt_3Oji99ByiRPr5F5d12fREgdR] of type [payment_intent.succeeded] failed: User not found!

My server.js:

```
    const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const stripe = require('stripe')('placeholder');
const app = express();
const endpointSecret = 'placeholder';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('placeholder');

const paymentMethodDomain = await 
  stripe.paymentMethodDomains.create({
  domain_name: 'domain.se',
  domain_name: 'localhost:1337',
});

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = admin.firestore();

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString()
  }
}))

// Function to handle Buy Button click
const handleBuyButtonClick = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { priceId } = req.body; // Assuming you send the priceId in the request body
    const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: 'localhost:1337/pages/verify-success.html', // Replace with your success URL
      cancel_url: 'localhost:1337/pages/verify-cancel.html', // Replace with your cancel URL
    });

    res.json({ sessionId: checkoutSession.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error handling Buy Button click:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
};

const handleEvent = (event) => {
  try {
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
        const session = event.data.object;
        const userId = session.customer;
      
        if (!user.exists) {
          console.error(`User not found for invoice payment succeeded event. User ID: ${userId}`);
          // Log the event or take appropriate actions
          // You might want to return a response to acknowledge the event
          return res.json({ success: false, message: 'User not found for invoice payment succeeded event.' });
        }
      
        // Continue processing for a found user
        handleSuccessfulInvoicePayment(userId);
        break;

      case 'checkout.session.completed':
        console.log(`Checkout session completed for user: ${userId}`);
        handleSuccessfulCheckout(userId);
        break;

      case 'customer.subscription.updated':
        // Handle subscription updated event
        break;

      case 'customer.subscription.created':
        // Handle subscription created event
        break;

      // Add other event handling cases as needed

      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error handling event: ${error}`);
  }
};

const handleSuccessfulCheckout = async (session) => {
  try {
    // Create or update the user document in your database with the subscription status
    const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);
    await userRef.update({ subscriptionStatus: 'paid' });

    // Retrieve additional information from the Stripe event
    const stripeCustomerId = session.customer;
    const stripeSubscriptionId = session.subscription;

    // Only update Firestore with Stripe-related fields if they exist
    const updateFields = {};
    if (stripeCustomerId) {
      updateFields.stripeCustomerID = stripeCustomerId;
    }
    if (stripeSubscriptionId) {
      updateFields.stripeSubscriptionID = stripeSubscriptionId;
    }

    if (Object.keys(updateFields).length > 0) {
      await userRef.update(updateFields);
    }

    console.log(`Subscription updated for user: ${userId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error handling successful checkout for user ${userId}:`, error);
  }
};

const handleSubscriptionEvent = async (subscriptionEvent) => {
  const userId = subscriptionEvent.customer;
  const subscriptionStatus = subscriptionEvent.status;

  const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);
  const user = await userRef.get();

  if (!user.exists) {
    console.error(`User not found for subscriptionEvent ${userId}`);
    // Return an appropriate response indicating "User not found"
    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'User not found for subscription' });
  }

  // Update the user document, create subscription document, etc.
  // ...
};

  // Update the user document
  await userRef.update({ subscriptionStatus });

  // Create a new subscription document
  const subscriptionData = {
    status: subscriptionStatus,
    // other subscription details
  };

  const subscriptionsRef = db.collection('subscriptions');
  await subscriptionsRef.doc(userId).set(subscriptionData);

app.post('/webhook/payment-intent-succeeded', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Inside the /webhook/payment-intent-succeeded endpoint
const { id } = req.body;
const findUserBySubscriptionId = async (subscriptionId) => {
  try {
    const userSnapshot = await db.collection('users').where('stripeSubscriptionID', '==', subscriptionId).get();

    if (userSnapshot.empty) {
      // User not found
      return null;
    }

    // Return the user data
    return userSnapshot.docs[0].data();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error finding user by subscription:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

// Later in the endpoint
const user = await findUserByPaymentIntent(id);
if (!user) {
  console.error(`User not found for payment_intent ${id}`);
  return res.json({ success: true, message: 'User not found, but event acknowledged.' });
}
// Continue processing for a found user

    if (!user) {
      console.error(`User not found for payment_intent ${id}`);
      // Handle the situation when the user is not found
      // For example, you might want to log the event and return a success response
      return res.json({ success: true, message: 'User not found, but event acknowledged.' });
    }

    // Continue processing for a found user
    // Your existing code for handling payment_intent.succeeded event

    res.json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error handling payment_intent.succeeded:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Your Stripe webhook endpoint
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), async (req, res) => {
  // The code for handling Stripe webhook events
  const payload = req.body;
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Webhook error:', err.message);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  handleEvent(event);

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({ received: true });
});

// Route to handle Buy Button click
app.post('/create-checkout-session', handleBuyButtonClick);

// Your other server setup and routes go here...

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I only put placeholders ofc.

Comment: Can somone help out

Comment: can you please show this function: ```findUserByPaymentIntent``` ?

Comment: also which endpoint are you using? ```'/webhook'``` or ```'/webhook/payment-intent-succeeded'```

Comment: I have updated the code since its been a week. Take a look.

 I dont know what endpoint, I can see the payment_intent.succeeded

Response
HTTP status code
200 (OK)
{
  "error": "Webhook handler failed. View function logs in Firebase."
}

for payment-intent-succeeded.

Comment: provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , specially `findUserByPaymentIntent()` to inspect `user` .

Comment: I only have findUserByPaymentIntent there nowhere else. Is that the problem here?

Comment: The function it self. how does it look? most likely your error is there.

Comment: Also i need you to go to the stripe dash - development - webhook . and tell me which endpoint is activated. because /webhook handles the repsonse differently than /webhook/payment-intent-succeeded . honestly /webhook looks better approach. but in order to give you a correct answer i need to understand more..

Comment: The code I posted is the only code I have except 2 TypeScripts. Non of those has findUserByPaymentIntent function.

Comment: I still dont get the difference but I got 1 test-mode webhook active. And that is: https://europe-west3-placeholder.cloudfunctions.net/ext-firestore-stripe-payments-handleWebhookEvents

Comment: Did you give up? @ElnaHaim